# OLAP and postgresql- tool or methodology?

Tags: postgresql, olap, aggregation, bigdata

I was reviewing some documents for making my database perform better and I came across with "OLAP" pre-aggregation term. I was wondering if OLAP is a tool or or methodology or approach. For example my DBMS is postgresql and I am working on a big databse. To speed up I have to use some aggregation and pre-aggregation methods. How OLAP can be helpful?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/aggregate_tables.php)? I think it might help you on how one can use OLAP aggregates.

Answer (score 1):

OLAP is a database role.  When storing OLAP data in the db, typically you aren't running live transactional information off the db, but rather keeping it around for analytical and business intelligence reasons.

It isn't a tool.  It isn't an approach either, since some approaches are needed for OLAP but some are helpful together in transactional environments as well.

In general you shouldn't think about speeding up an application by incorporating OLAP into it.  Instead you would look at separating out reporting functions into a separate db server, and import the data periodically, and then separate data feeds from operation data stores, etc.  This is a very different field than transactional application development.